# How to set SSL certificate from gcloud?

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I have an application that turns like the storaged database in Google Cloud is linked by HTTP and not HTTPS which makes problems with all the private networks that the app can work on them.
I want to set ssl certificate for my Storage. I searched and found a lot of options and tried all of them an get nothing.
now I'm here, These are the commands I already made:

```
mkdir ssl_cert
cd ssl_cert
openssl genrsa -out example.key 2048
openssl req -new -key example.key -out example.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in example.csr -signkey example.key -out example.crt
```

then I wrote this commmand:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create [SSL_CERTIFICATE] \
--certificate [CRT_FILE_PATH] \
--private-key [KEY_FILE_PATH]
```

Of course I exchanged the first [] with 'my_ss_cert' the second [] with 'example.key' and the third [] with 'example.crt' but I got an error that both example.key and example.crt files does not found.
after all the command I anderstand it's suppose to be there.

it looks like:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create riki \ --certificate example.crt \ -- 
private-key example.key
```

and i get this error:
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssl-certificates.create) unrecognized arguments:
   --certificate
  example.crt
   --private-key
  example.key
  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS

any idea?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you are setting your file paths?

Comment: If you run `ls`, do you see `example.key` and `example.crt` in the file listing?

Comment: Vilas- yes i can see them.

Answer (score 1):

The value for `[SSL_CERTIFICATE]` is your user-defined name by which you wish to associate the cert.... e.g. `fred`. The two `PATH` values must be to your `example.crt` and `example.key` respectively:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create fred \
--certificate=./example.crt \
--private-key=./example.key \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Comment: Hi. I did exactly as you said, and i get this line: Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/wordproject-249810/global/sslCertificates/fred].
NAME  CREATION_TIMESTAMP
fred  2019-09-28T11:20:43.803-07:00.
what should i do now?

Comment: That's success! You've uploaded your self-signed (!) certificate as a Google Cloud Platform `ssl-certifcate`. This `ssl-certificate` could then be configured with an HTTP/S Load-Balancer to proxy traffic to your application: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#create-lb-managed-certs **NB** You should not use a self-signed certificate for anything but testing. You may wish to consider using a service such as Let's Encrypt to obtain a certificate for a domain that you own and using that instead.

Comment: 1. thanl you!
2. i have to say: i lose my hands and my legs in all this mess... i have no idea what to do. pls explain me: what i tried to do is: that when i connecting to the mysql db- it will ne by https protocol and not htto as now. did you anderstand this from me?

Comment: It will be challenging to explain this via Stack Overflow messages. However, if you're looking to secure MySQL, you should consider a different approach. It's unclear whether you're running MySQL on a Compute Engine instance or using Cloud SQL. If you're using Cloud SQL see: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl